# Store images in Apache Kafka?

Tags: java, apache-kafka

Do any big users of Kafka (e.g. LinkedIn) store uploaded images in Kafka? I like the architectural simplicity of putting *everything* into the log, but I am concerned that it may not be workable in practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theoretically there is no restriction as you could easily store images as binary in Kafka Queue. But there could be other issues .. I would try to put some thought on this

There is a `message.max.bytes` parameter in the consumer config and the default value is `1000000`. This is done actually to prevent brokers from running out of memory because the consumer does not have option for streaming a message and has to allocate memory to be able to read the message. A workaround could be to compress messages in Kafka in order to save spaces.

The most suitable condition I could find is to write your own client implementation by passing pre-allocation of send&receive buffers, providing zero-copy file transfer over Kafka as seen in [this](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/kafka-users/201309.mbox/browser) discussion.

You need to check if it is possible to make such effort to achieve the same.

Comment: Just curious, why do you say that the consumer does not have an option to stream messages? The Kafka Consumer example suggests using only a KafkaStream which is definitely a stream. I have used a consumer with a very large fetch-size of around 50 MB (you can try it with the console consumer) and the memory consumption does not appreciably increase with the fetch/message size. Do you have an experience that suggests otherwise? Or do you mean that you need to hold at least one message at a time in memory, in which case you do see increased memory usage, but this cannot be avoided.

Comment: the brokers need to allocate buffers in order to read messages. in the consumer configuration page the `fetch.message.max.bytes` property says `The number of byes of messages to attempt to fetch for each topic-partition in each fetch request. These bytes will be read into memory for each partition, so this helps control the memory used by the consumer.`